# Google Anthos on prem installation

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-anthos

Is it possible to install Google Anthos on prem or ist this a pure cloud service?
In some cases in might be useful to manage cluster without a cloud connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anthos is an *on the cloud service* provided by Google. Whilst you might not be able to have a completely isolated installation of Anthos on-prem with zero external access, [Anthos on BareMetal](https://cloud.google.com/anthos/gke/docs/bare-metal/1.6/concepts/about-bare-metal) allows you to make use of your on prem infrastructure to get the full capabilities of Anthos.

With [Anthos on BareMetal](https://cloud.google.com/anthos/gke/docs/bare-metal/1.6/concepts/about-bare-metal) the external connectivity is only used for the minimal control plane functionality of managing your clusters via the Cloud Console. Almost all the other components of Anthos reside on-prem in your infrastructure.

***Useful resources***.
[Introduction to Anthos on bare metal](https://cloud.google.com/anthos/gke/docs/bare-metal/1.6/quickstart) by a Developer Advocate at Google.
[About Anthos on BareMetal](https://cloud.google.com/anthos/gke/docs/bare-metal/1.6/concepts/about-bare-metal)